Drop a postgres database
Apparently DROP DATABASE doesn't do anything. But it also doesn't show a warning. What's going on?
# \l
                                     List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 some_db_2024_11 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
                 |          |          |             |             | some_db=CTc/postgres +
                 |          |          |             |             | some_db=CTc/postgres
 some_db_2024_12 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 postgres        | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 template0       | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres-# drop database some_db_2024_11
postgres-# \l
                                     List of databases
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 some_db_2024_11 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
                 |          |          |             |             | some_db=CTc/postgres +
                 |          |          |             |             | some_db=CTc/postgres
 some_db_2024_12 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 postgres        | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |
 template0       | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1       | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                 |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres-#


It did not anything as you did not ask it to. You need to tell the server you are submitting the statement, in other words it should be drop database some_db_2024_11;. Also make sure you are not connected to some_db_2024_11 when you do this. Read psql. Shortcut, go to the  Examples section.

Do you mean: add a semicolon?

Yes, from the psql link Entering SQL Commands: At the prompt, the user can type in SQL commands. Ordinarily, input lines are sent to the server when a command-terminating semicolon is reached. An end of line does not terminate a command. Thus commands can be spread over several lines for clarity. If the command was sent and executed without error, the results of the command are displayed on the screen.
